# How do I store data in a non-local database in iOS app development?

Tags: ios, database, storage

I am new to programming. I am starting to look at designing an app. I have went through a good amount of lectures, tutorials, and books regarding programming. I have a pretty strong grasp of concepts of designing an iOS app, but my main question is, how do I store data outside of a user's iPhone? If I want to create a social app where everyone can view and interact with each other's data, where do I store that data? I know this is a loaded question. I know there is sooo much out there, but if someone can lead me in the right direction of where to start, or at least topic concepts of what to research I would really appreciate it. Thank you everyone for your time in reading and responding.

Comment: FYI - As someone new to programming, trying to write a client/server social application as your first project is like hopping in the space shuttle for your very first flying lesson. Start smaller and learn a bit first.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy - you can look at services like Parse.com to make things easier, but walk before you run

Comment: There are many cloud solutions that'll work just fine. A very popular and robust one is named Parse: [https://parse.com/](https://parse.com/)

Comment: cloud based web app with objective-c: http://objective-cloud.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although the comments are right, this way would be a large jump (speaking from experience from going from a intermediate level of Obj-C to full Database integration) there is a lot of information to learn.

But if your willing:

How web service's work (generally) there is a hosted MySQL Database on a web server that contains your information. You use a PHP file to access the information in the Database (INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) and return results using something called JSON.

Your iOS app will connect to a web service by executing the URL of the php file on your website. This php file will send the actual commands to the database. The database will then return the information to the php file and the php file will then output the database information that you wanted in JSON format. Your app then will read the JSON Format store the information into variables and that you can use.

**Things to look into are:**

- MySQL
- phpMyAdmin
- PHP -> mySQLi Prepared Statements (To prevent SQL Injection
  Attacks)
- PHP -> JSON formatting
- Obj-C/Swift -> JSON Parsing

To learn about databases and php I would look at a youtube channel called Tinkernut. He did a series on a login system using html and php. Although its not an app, the information is very relevant and you can learn a lot from his videos. He goes over MySQL, and interacting with Databases in PHP. I would watch his entire website basics series to learn about how databases work online. Then the only change you need to do is output the information in JSON Format for your app to read.

Comment: @Octavio, before you start learning vanilla-PHP and MySQL, consider using a web framework with a sane language, like python (django, turbogears), ruby (ruby-on-rails), groovy (grails),…

Comment: Why was this down voted? This answered his question on what direction to go if he wants to learn how to do it himself.

Comment: Your answer suggests that PHP and MySQL are the only option to go. This is untrue and in my opinion the worst path possible.

Comment: I never said that this was the only option and I do not need to list all options, but it is an option and is very common practice in both websites and app development. Just because you personally do not prefer this way, you cannot speak for everyone. This is a powerful method and would be very educational to someone wanting to learn. It can give a new developer great insight on the power of databases with mobile applications. So instead of you bashing an idea because you don't like it, provide your own input and give a recommendation. A better way can always be debated.

Comment: voting is a valid form of feedback. If you consider this bashing, this is not the optimal site for you.